# python , i need to use 2 functions to create another new one which includes only the 10 elements with the biggest name of the previous list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-requests

How can i build a function for example named genes1(x) that will take a parameter. This parameter is a list of strings. The function will return a new list that has the permeter elements but is sorted by string length (from smallest to longest).
and THEN
Using the function i just created (genes1) and another  genes2() which includes all the genes , create another function named genes3 that takes no argument. The function will return the answer to the question: What are the 10 genes with the biggest name ?
i tried this for the first scale and worked (but for the second what i tried didnt)

```
`enter code here`
def genes1(x):
    return [sorted(x, key=len)]
def genes3():
    c = [genes1(x)] 
    for x in c[-1:-11]:
        print (x)
#or tried this:
    return c[-1:-11]
```

Answer (score 0):

A function that takes no parameters needs to have all required values in its own or in global scope. `genes3()` makes use of variable `x` which is not defined anywhere.

Assuming, that your function `genes2()` returns a list with the names of the genes, like `gene_names = ["name1", "name2"]`, you need to call that function in genes3 like this:

```
def genes3():
    gene_names = genes2()
    c = genes1(gene_names) # as genes1(x) returns the list you seem to want, no brackets are needed here
    return c[-1:-11]
```

Finally call genes3

```
result = genes3()
print(result)
```